# htaccess redirect only if domain matches

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a problem where I need to redirect my domain before it hits php. By the time it hits the ability to execute a header, it is too late.

How can I do

```
if (domain == 'www.example.com')
redirect www.domain.com;
```

in my .htaccess?

Comment: seriously, why can't it just be like what you wrote?

Comment: the above code sample is php. I need it to not hit the php

Comment: fair enough. i just think htaccess domain specific language could be a lot more sane.

Answer (score 21):

Using mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: I think the slash at domain.com/$1 needs to be removed, because it already comes in the $1

Comment: @webjunkie As of apachee 2.0+, the leading slash is removed from the URI when used to be match against rules in an htaccess file because it's automatically a per directory match. URI's put through rules in server or vhost config will still have leading slashes. OP asked for rules in htaccess.

Comment: Oh okay I used this in server config. But might be good to know for future visitors.

Comment: @webjunkie That's why sometimes, even if it's for htaccess, I'll make the regex: `^/?(.*)$` instead, to match out the leading slash if there is one, in case it gets used elsewhere.

Comment: What does [NC] do?

Comment: @digout no case matching

Answer (score 20):

As of Apache 2.4 you can use an `<If>` Directive to achieve what you suggested:

```
<If "req('Host') == 'www.example.com'">
  RedirectMatch (.*) http://www.example2.com$1
</If>
```

For a case-insensitive version that matches with or without the www you can do:

```
<If "req('Host') =~ /example.com/i">
  RedirectMatch (.*) http://www.example2.com$1
</If>
```

Sources:

- Apache Blog: [New in httpd 2.4: If, ElseIf, and Else](https://blogs.apache.org/httpd/entry/new_in_httpd_2_4)
- Apache 2.4 Documentation: [If Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer ^^ 

I would add the **301** in there though:

```RewriteEngine On
            <If "req('Host') =~ /example.com/i">
                RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*) https://www.example2.com$1
            </If>```